# Session Setting in Profile through metadata

Tags: apex, deployment, profile, metadata, package.xml

Is this possible to update **session-setting** in profile using metadata deployment i.e through package.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Should be. I use a deployment tool which simplifies this for me, but if you're looking to pull it you might want to check workbench --> Info --> Metadata Types & Components --> ProfileSessionSetting.

What's highlighted in blue is just the profile name.

[image]

This'll give you the name to include in your package.xml to pull/deploy.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilesessionsetting.htm

[image]